# Dubious dupe target for JavaScript spread syntax

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, canonical

I came across a question asking "What does `...` mean in JavaScript?" I assumed such a basic question must have been asked before, and unsurprisingly I found several similar questions:

[Javascript what is “…array”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47309456/javascript-what-is-array)
[what are those triple dot inside the array? marked it with a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886728/what-are-those-triple-dot-inside-the-array-marked-it-with-a-comment)
[What does three dots in Javascript means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39413273/what-does-three-dots-in-javascript-means)
[What are javascript “…array” parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54165824/what-are-javascript-array-parameters)
[What is this syntax and clearly meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45671807/what-is-this-syntax-and-clearly-meaning)

All of these questions are closed as duplicates of another question: [Spread Syntax ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559918/spread-syntax-es6). However, all of them as well as the question I was originally looking at are asking what it *means*, while this one assumes that you already know what it means and instead asks about a specific usage of it. Is this really an appropriate dupe target? Is there a better one that could be used instead?

Comment: I think I see your point, but do you really think it would be more helpful to redirect people asking these questions to an answer stating *"That"s spread syntax, go read more about it in [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34559918/spread-syntax-es6)"* rather than linking them directly to said Q/A?

Comment: Or, you could write an answer to the question they're closed as a dupe of, in which you explain what it is as well.

Comment: If you want the very generic solution, then go with [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript) But I find it's *too* generic - I just find what the asker needs from there and link them to that one. It works fine, even if the dupe target is something they couldn't search for (e.g., "spread syntax" without knowing the term). After all the dupe notice says that an *answer* to your question can be found at this other place. Not that your question 1:1 including terminology to it.

Comment: IMO no it is not an appropriate dupe target. It asks three questions, to begin with. The answers are a little all over the place because of it.

Answer (score -1):

I think that *the question* is a good dupetarget, as it asks "What exactly is the use of spread syntax?" and thats exactly the same question all the others had. Yet, the answers only briefly cover that point.

I'll raise a bounty on the question, so that this dupetarget becomes more useful.